# Why did Italian omit the Latin prefix 'ex-' in 'prosciutto'?

Tags: etymology, latin

> [prosciutto (n.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=prosciutto) 
>       Italian spiced ham, 1911, from Italian,
>   alteration (probably by influence of prosciugato "dried") of presciutto,
>   from *pre-*, here an intensive prefix, + *-sciutto*,
>   from Latin *exsuctus* "lacking juice, dried up," past participle of *exsugere* "suck out, draw out moisture,"
>   from ***ex-* "out"** (see [ex-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ex-&allowed_in_frame=0)) + *sugere* "to suck" (see [sup (v.2)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=sup&allowed_in_frame=0)).

1. The above implies Italian's neglect or omission of the Latin prefix ***ex-***. Am I right?
2. Why was *pre-* conserved? What exactly did *pre-* intensify? Why did ***ex-*** not suffice?

Comment: "*pre*-conserved": romance languages didn't just born overnight, they all took several centuries to form and they're, of course, still evolving; it may well be also that the prefix has been slowly dropped over time for usage reasons.

Comment: @Charo Grazie! Alas, I know too little Italian.

Comment: Italian pronunciation of 'proscuitto' : http://www.vocabolaudio.com/it/prosciutto

Comment: @LePressentiment, that colon after the /u/ is wrong. I checked a few examples ([formaggio](http://www.vocabolaudio.com/it/formaggio), [mozzarella](http://www.vocabolaudio.com/it/mozzarella), [pancetta](http://www.vocabolaudio.com/it/pancetta)) and it seems that [vocabolaudio.com](http://www.vocabolaudio.com/) got it wrong all over the place

Comment: @WalterTross +1. Thanks; I will retain my comment above for others' knowledge.

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer to your question, please consider the option to "accept" it by clicking a checkmark next to the answer.

Comment: @I.M. Thanks. i have just requested elucidation on question 2 above.

Answer (score 10):

1. No. The prefix *ex-* is not vanished: it has turned the alveolar sound [s] into a postalveolar one, [ʃ]. Otherwise, we'd have something like *“prosutto”.
2. and 3. By the above, there is no disappearance to explain. Moreover, “laziness” and “irrationality”, per se, are not very scientific or useful concepts, are they? Either we limit ourselves to some precise question (the decreased emission of breath when emitting a given phoneme, say), or we are talking about nothing.

Comment: +1. Thanks. I revised my OP. Better? Also, will you please answer my updated question 2 above?